# Ubuntu 16.04 boot freezes intermittently at boot

Tags: boot, 16.04, dual-boot, grub2, amd-graphics

Recently I've installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my desktop, the specs are:

Processor:
AMD Phenom(tm) II X4 965 Processor × 4 
GPU:
Radeon HD 5850

And sometimes, right after I press enter on grub (I dual boot with windows), the screen goes blank and the computer freezes, the only way out is to reset it. The weird thing is that it only happens like, 50% of the time. Sometimes it works as usual. After boot, the system works as expected.

I suspect it has something to do with the video card, but I have no clue on how to investigate it. I don't know how can I access some kind of log of the crash, because it happens on the boot start and I get literally no input.

Do you guys have any idea on how to solve this? I will be glad to provide more information, if needed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If its happening after the loading of grub, its unlikely to be a hardware issue so much as a driver issue. If the freezes are causing corruption you can use something like http://www.supergrubdisk.org/ to scan and fix boot partitions.

If its a driver issue I would highly recommend using the open source Radeon driver NOT the AMD Catalyst driver if you can support it. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver

Outside of this the only real way to test graphic card failures, is try the system with a different card and see if the problem goes away, but if its happening intermittently that may not be easy to check unless you have another graphics card laying around.

Answer (score -1):

If you install Ubuntu on your PC and it don't boot, answer me: does the local disk is appearing during boot?
If not, then it means that you installed Ubuntu on your boot partition, you should check it out

Comment: You are not giving an answer to the question. Please rephrase your response as it is unclear what you want the user to do.

Comment: I think I understand the answer this guy is trying to write: he is saying that if OP installed Ubuntu in the UEFI partition, it won't boot at all.